# Why is SpriteKit coordinate system different from UIKit coordinate system in the orientation of the vertical axis?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, uikit, coordinate-systems

In `SpriteKit`, the default coordinate system has its origin at the lower left of the drawing area.

In `UIKit`, the default coordinate system has its origin at the upper left of the drawing area.

I'm familiar with `UIKit` but new to `SpriteKit`. so I'm very confused every time I use `SpriteKit`'s coordinate system.

I know that there are some solutions to "flip" the `SpriteKit`'s coordinate system. However, I still don't know the reason for this difference.

In other words, why not apply a standard coordinate system for all?

[image]

Comment: Actually, SK’s origin is now in the centre of the screen so you can v8sualise the screen like a sheet of graph paper.

Comment: Believe it or not, it actually is standard.  UIKit is more for application design, and a lot of UI Designers do  a top down coordinate system where it makes sense that a + y goes top to bottom because that is how we read, top to bottom, left to right.  SpriteKit is a garaphics/gaming deign,  the concept where + y means a concept of up, so it makes sense to have y go in a reverse direction.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Post that as an answer. And also, I find the SpriteKit way easier to use because that's the way grids and graphs are lay out in school, so it seems more natural